# Overwriting only the desired rows in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview, rows

The intent of the application is to show all available hours in the day. If there already exists some scheduling it appears on its own line, otherwise the line will come in white showing the availability of that time.

Schedules are displayed in the DataGridView according to the day that I select on the calendar

Example:

[image: Example]

**The image above shows how it should stay**, Currently the datagrid is populated as follows (clinical work from 08:00 to 20:00)

```
 private void frmAgenda_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string data = agenda.SelectionRange.Start.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        for (int cont = 8; cont <= 19; cont++)
        {
            string[] row = new string[] { "", "", data, cont.ToString() + ":00", "" };
            dtgrdAgendamentos.Rows.Add(row);
            string[] row2 = new string[] { "", "", data, cont.ToString() + ":30", "" };
            dtgrdAgendamentos.Rows.Add(row2);
        }

        string[] row3 = new string[] { "", "", data, "20:00", "" };
        dtgrdAgendamentos.Rows.Add(row3);
    }
```

And then when I select one day he carries the information from the database MSSQL 2005 as follows:

```
string day = agenda.SelectionRange.Start.ToString();

        try
        {
            conexao.Open();
            adap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT paciente_codigo , consulta_nomepaciente , consulta_data, consulta_hora, consulta_valor, consulta_id, consulta_recibo FROM consulta WHERE consulta_data =  '" + day + "'", conexao);
            ds = new DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds, "Patients_Schedules");
            dtgrdAgendamentos.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dtgrdAgendamentos.Columns[5].Visible = false;
            dtgrdAgendamentos.Columns[6].Visible = false;                

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conexao.Close();
        }
```

Obviously it replaces what had been loaded in the Load, but need it to check the time that a record is saved in the database (consulta_hora column), and put that into their schedule online datagrid. In our example were scheduled and saved in the database three schedules on 5/13/2014, one at 8:00, 10:30 and the other at 12:00 ... the application should put these three schedules in their respective places in the DataGridView, and available leave with nothing, as in the example image.

I appreciate the help because I have no idea how to do this. Perhaps the current form is not the most appropriate.

P.S.: [I found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818382/how-to-overwrite-a-row-in-datagridview-if-same-datetime-is-already-in-a-row), but do not know how to use.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to describe what's wrong with your code. I did understand what is your app supposed to do, but I didn't understand which part you're unable to implement. Are you having difficulties with fulfilling the datagrid with "empty" schedules?

Comment: The sample image I filled out manually, just to show how it should be. Currently it loads the information shown with the first method, but to load the information from database in DataGridView it overwrites the data rather than "fit them" on the desired line. In our example would be only 3 rows relating to schedules.  @Tarec "Are you having difficulties with fulfilling the datagrid with "empty" schedules?" >> Yes!